# csvsimple csvreader doesn't use option separator

Tags: csv, csvsimple

My csv is separated by tabs.

When loading it with `\csvautotabular` the option `separator=tab` works fine.
But when loading it with with `\csvreader` just like in the example of the documentation it only prints out the first data line.

Pictures to see the output are appended at the end.

my file with tabs (table-data/parse_size_out.tsv):

```
benchmark   num_post_packed_blocks  num_clb
ch_intrinsics.v 295 65
diffeq1.v   299 36
diffeq2.v   198 29
mkPktMerge.v    509 27
raygentop.v 634 106
stereovision3.v 54  13
```

reformatted with commas (table-data/parse_size_out_commas.csv):

```
benchmark,num_post_packed_blocks,num_clb
ch_intrinsics.v,295,65
diffeq1.v,299,36
diffeq2.v,198,29
mkPktMerge.v,509,27
raygentop.v,634,106
stereovision3.v,54,13
```

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvautotabular[
separator=tab,
respect underscore=true
]{table-data/parse_size_out.tsv}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}\hline%
\bfseries Benchmark & \bfseries \#blocks
\csvreader[
separator=tab,
respect underscore=true,
head to column names
]{table-data/parse_size_out.tsv}{benchmark=\benchmark,num_post_packed_blocks=\numblocks}{%
\\\benchmark & \numblocks
}%
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}\hline%
\bfseries Benchmark & \bfseries \#blocks
\csvreader[
respect underscore=true,
head to column names
]{table-data/parse_size_out_commas.csv}{benchmark=\benchmark,num_post_packed_blocks=\numblocks}{%
\\\benchmark & \numblocks
}%
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`\csvautotabular`:

[image: csvautotabular]

`\csvreader` with tabbed file:

[image: csvreader with tabs]

`\csvreader` with file with commas:

[image: csvreader with commas]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

You should load the (maintained) `l3` version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvautotabular[
  separator=tab,
  respect underscore=true
]{a.tsv}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}\hline
\bfseries Benchmark & \bfseries \#blocks
\csvreader[
  separator=tab,
  respect underscore=true,
  head to column names
]{a.tsv}{benchmark=\benchmark,num_post_packed_blocks=\numblocks}{%
  \\\benchmark & \numblocks
}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}\hline
\bfseries Benchmark & \bfseries \#blocks
\csvreader[
  respect underscore=true,
  head to column names
]{b.csv}{benchmark=\benchmark,num_post_packed_blocks=\numblocks}{%
  \\\benchmark & \numblocks
}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(I changed the file names, edit them back.)

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks, I just noticed that myself. I loaded it some time ago with  
\usepackage[13]{csvsimple} because I took the letter "l" for the number "1".
And then sharelatex threw an error, so I thought it would have the newest package anyways and removed the [13]. Sometime just copy paste would save someone from hours of struggling.